# Function that reads each word in a string and prints each word on different line with C

Tags: c

This is my code so far, I need to still figure out how to add `'\0'` to the end of the string and advance nextindex to the beginning of the next word.

```
 * inputs: str - the string,
 * if str is NULL, return the index of the next word in the string
 * AND place a '\0' at the end of that word.
 */
int nextword(char *str)
{
    // create two static variables - these stay around across calls
    static char *s;
    static int nextindex;
    int thisindex;
    // reset the static variables
    if (str != NULL)
    {
        s = str;
        thisindex = 0;
        // TODO:  advance this index past any leading spaces
        while (s[thisindex]=='\n' || s[thisindex]=='\t' || s[thisindex]==' '                )
          thisindex++;  

    }
    else
    {
        // set the return value to be the nextindex
        thisindex = nextindex;
    }
    // if we aren't done with the string...
    if (thisindex != -1)
    {
        // TODO: two things
        // 1: place a '\0' after the current word
        // 2: advance nextindex to the beginning
        // of the next word

    }
    return thisindex;
}
```

And I want the following code

```
char *str = "Welcome everybody! Today is a beautiful day\t\n";
int i = nextword(str);
while(i != -1)
{
    printf("%s\n",&(str[i]));
    i = nextword(NULL);
}
```

to output

```
Welcome 
everybody!
Today 
is
a 
beautiful
day
```

Comment: This looks like provided code for homework. Have you tried anything? What is your question?

Comment: How would I add '\0' to the end of the word without changing the thisindex value that need to be returned?

Comment: are you familiar with strtok() ? or is part of the assignment that you can't use it ?

Comment: I cannot use the string library.

Comment: can you use ctype.h ? (i.e. isspace() ) ?

Comment: No, just stdio.h and stdlib.h

Comment: Removed homework tag as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @Michael_19 see answers below. Hopefully the idea you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're asking for help, when the required action is contained in your code already:

```
    // TODO: two things
    // 1: place a '\0' after the current word
    // 2: advance nextindex to the beginning
    // of the next word
```

So let's break it down.

1. You need to search through your string until you find a space.  You already have a loop that does the reverse.  You replace the character that follows your word with a `'\0'`.  Be careful not to run past the end of your string.
2. I think number 2 doesn't require explanation, except to say that you need to make sure that if you find yourself at the end of the input string (in number 1 above), you set `nextindex` to -1.