# Program that edits string and prints each word individually with C

Tags: c

I keep getting the error segmentation fault (core dumped) when I run my progam.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    int nextword(char *str);

    int main(void)
    {
      char str[] = "Hello! Today is a beautiful day!!\t\n";
      int i = nextword(str);
       while(i != -1)
         {
          printf("%s\n",&(str[i]));
          i = nextword(NULL);
          }
      return 0;
      }

    int nextword(char *str)
    {
      // create two static variables - these stay around across calls
      static char *s;
      static int nextindex;
      int thisindex;
      // reset the static variables
      if (str != NULL)
        {
          s = str;
          thisindex = 0;
          // TODO:  advance this index past any leading spaces
          while (s[thisindex]=='\n' || s[thisindex]=='\t' || s[thisindex]==' ' )
        thisindex++;

        }
      else
        {
          // set the return value to be the nextindex
          thisindex = nextindex;
        }
      // if we aren't done with the string...
      if (thisindex != -1)
        {
          nextindex = thisindex;
          // TODO: two things
          // 1: place a '\0' after the current word
          // 2: advance nextindex to the beginning
          // of the next word
          while (s[nextindex] != ' ' && s[nextindex] != '\0')
        nextindex++;

          str[nextindex] = '\0';
          nextindex++;
        }
      return thisindex;
    }
```

The goal of the program is to print each word in the string str[] to the console on a new line. I am a beginning programmer and this is an assignment so I must use this type of format (no string library allowed). I just would like to know where I went wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Segmentation fault is caused by the invalid assignment of variables. This may be because of the incorrect placement of data on an array.

Comment: Thanks on providing full code I can cut&paste and try - good question etiquette :-)

Comment: No problem! I thought it would be most helpful instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: Stepping through your code the issue may be at `46                while (s[nextindex] != ' ' || s[nextindex] != '\0')` quick guess this should be an && test

Comment: Your printf() is dereferncing a single character as an address in memory. I'd guess your crash is there.

Comment: I just changed it, I get the same error when I run the program. I thought you had to pass the adress of the first character of the string if you use %s ?

Comment: @Michael_19 You still get a crash after fixing your loop because you're never checking for end-of-string when you advance `nextindex`.  I answered your question yesterday and gave you two important points to consider.  So far you haven't followed them.

Comment: Doesn't my while loop check for the end of string, when I am advancing nextindex++ ? @paddy

Comment: @Michael_19 I would have written it as *(str+i), but what you had before (&str[i]) should work too.

Comment: @jimp those are not the same. (str+i) and &(str[i]) are the same in C. the deref operator on the first should not be present.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I've seen this program before in another one of your questions...  [Function that reads each word in a string and prints each word on different line with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684380/function-that-reads-each-word-in-a-string-and-prints-each-word-on-different-line/12684640)

You have an error in your loop:

```
while (s[nextindex] != ' ' || s[nextindex] != '\0')
```

Use `&&`, not `||`.  That loop as it is will never terminate because at least one of the two conditions will always be true.

Then you have to fix your other problem (failing to detect end-of-string).  This will do it:

```
if( str[nextindex] != 0 ) {
    str[nextindex] = '\0';
    nextindex++;
} else {
    nextindex = -1;
}
```

Comment: But if I use && wouldn't both condition have to be true? Which would never happen...

Comment: Um, yeah.  If you use `&&` the loop will continue while both conditions are true (ie it is NOT a space and it is NOT zero).  As soon as either a space or a zero is encountered, the loop stops.

Comment: Take this as a good solution for the first problem, but another thing is that when you use the nextword(NULL); statement, this is the next problem on your program that causes segmentation dump.

Comment: OH okay, I understand what you are saying now. I was confused with the use of !=.

Comment: @ChinoCarloSedilla Why would that be?  Don't you understand `static`?

Comment: So the last '\0' at the end of the string is found and then I do nextindex++ , is this what is causing the problem?

Comment: does your compiler allow this? int nextword(char *str)

Comment: @Michael_19 Yes, I expect so.  You have to set `nextindex` to -1 if you encounter the null-terminator (because it's the end of the string, and you defined the value -1 to mean there are no more words).  If you don't distinguish between end-of-word and end-of-string you will skip straight past the end of the string and get a segmentation fault in successive calls.  By the way, didn't you also want to skip tabs and newlines?

Comment: Yes @paddy also, does my use of NULL make sense? This part of the code was given to me by my professor so I find it hard to believe that it can be wrong.

Comment: @paddy Does your compiler allow the assignment of NULL to a function that requires a pointer as a parameter? My compiler does not allow that. Why not see it for yourself. :)

Comment: Yep.  NULL is implicitly cast as a pointer type in many compilers, or is defined as `(void*)0`.  If yours doesn't allow it then explicitly cast it: `(char*)NULL`.  Either way, that particular compiler error is not responsible for the segmentation fault.

Comment: @paddy ahh, thanks for that sir. ^_^ but when I was solving the problem using debuglines, I have noticed that the program wont continue on that line.

Comment: NULL is intrinsically cast-able to any pointer type in C. And I've *never* seen a C-compiler that doesn't allow a NULL passed for an address, which is all a formal pointer is for a parameter; a typed variable containing an address (unless it is void, in which case it can be anything because it is nothing, love that!). What C-compiler are you using anyway, because now I'm intrigued?

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, I just have misunderstood the lines of codes when I was trying to debug it. Sorry for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble following the logic of your code, but for a start, having

```
i = nextword(NULL);
```

in the loop of your main won't accomplish much.  Did you mean to iterate over the remainder of the string from which you had removed a word instead?

Comment: The purpose of it was to skip over the first 'if' statement because the first word has been printed already.

Comment: Invoking nextword(NULL) for each iteration of the loop isn't going to help you with that goal.  Nor is it going to modify the value for i in your inner loop: you will always have the same value i and your loop will run forever.  It will also be one cause for the segmentation fault.  I also agree with paddy's other comments.